# Can we create different users which see specific content types in Strapi?

Tags: strapi

Do we have the possibility to create different users which see specific content types in Strapi?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd just need to create a tagging system, you can do this by creating a user field, that takes in a list of tags essentially then associate content to user tags and vice versa to give you a many to many scenario.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the advice. I will do it